# Automatically Being Logged Out Lubuntu

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu

I'm being logged out on Lubuntu and I don't know why. Whenever I open it up it gives me the error about Xorg and it says it crashed with SIBART. I previously upgraded from 15.10, and I feel like it made the logouts more frequent as I can't really go 30mins-1h without losing my session.

EDIT: Someone wanted `uname -a` output so here it is for easy access:
`Linux GeminiTwo 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:41:41 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: 15.10 is End of Life, no longer supported. There's no point in troubleshooting. Install 16.04 and ask again if the symptom persists (it won't).

Comment: Sorry, didn't know. 16.04 had some problems on LiveUSB last time I checked so I guess I didn't use it. Will upgrading break anything? I need to know before I upgrade.

Comment: Just upgraded and reworded the question completely. Stopped using for now, will go in and grab logs.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the output of `uname -a` Thank you for helping us help you/

Comment: Linux GeminiTwo 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:41:41 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux